# Data Access with Async and Sync needs

Tags: c#, async-await

Is there a best practice for a design for a data access layer that could have both a need for Async and Non-Async calls?

I've seen some other posts that seem to be saying that using Task.Run on async calls is a "work-around" to calling async methods synchronously.

Example of a method I have (service layer) that could be leveraged both ways.

```
public override async Task<DataAccess.Fight> Insert(DataAccess.Fight item)
{
      await UnitOfWork.Fight.Insert(item);
      return item;
}
```

Thanks.
v.

Comment: Implement both async and non-async methods, and use the common naming convention, name all async methods "SomethingSomething**Async**".

Comment: Don’t simply wrap a sync method in a Task.Run() when you are dealing with I/O.   Such is a waste of a compute thread.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a best practice for a design for a data access layer that could have both a need for Async and Non-Async calls?

First, I'd recommend *only* exposing asynchronous methods. Data access, being I/O-based, is inherently asynchronous, so only exposing asynchronous methods is IMO an acceptable solution.

If you really *need* both asynchronous and synchronous methods, I recommend using the [bool argument hack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx), which allows you to have both synchronous and asynchronous APIs without duplicating any logic.

> I've seen some other posts that seem to be saying that using Task.Run on async calls is a "work-around" to calling async methods synchronously.

I believe you are referring to the thread pool hack, also covered in my article. This would not work if your code depends on any context (e.g., `HttpContext.Current`). It also can shift your code's expected environment from a single-threaded (implicitly synchronized) execution to a free-threaded environment with the possibility of parallelism. *Most* code is OK with this, but this does illustrate that "just wrap it in `Task.Run` and then block" is not a solution for every scenario.